# Random matrix with determinant not zero in Maxima

Tags: matrix, random, moodle, maxima, determinants

I want to generate a matrix with random entries such that the determinant of that matrix is not zero using Maxima and further down the line implement this in STACK for Moodle. I am completely new to working with Maxima (or any CAS for that matter), so I have been going through various examples I found online and have so far managed to get this:

Generating a 2x2 random matrix with 0 or 1 (for simplicity reasons) and calculating its determinant:

```
g[i,j]:=1-random(2);
M1:genmatrix(g,2,2);
dM1:determinant(M1);
```

For the next step I wanted to define a matrix M2 as follows:

```
M2:(if dM1#0 then M1 else ***)
```

If the determinant of the matrix M1 is already not zero, fine, I'll go with that, but I am struggling with the else-part. I was thinking of creating a loop that generates new random numbers `g[i,j]` for `M1` until I get a matrix with determinant not zero, but am unsure on how to do that or if there are other options.

In addition: as I mentioned this is ultimately something I want to implement in STACK for moodle (question will be to solve a system of linear equations with the generated matrix being the matrix of this system), so I don't know if there are any limitations on using if and while loops in STACK, so if somebody is aware of known problems I would appreciate any input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can say `for ... do ... return(something)` to yield `something` from the for-loop, which can be assigned to a variable. In this case it looks like this works as intended:

```
(%i9) M2: for i thru 10
            do (genmatrix (lambda ([i, j], 1 - random(2)), 2, 2),
                if determinant(%%) # 0 then return(%%));
                            [ 1  0 ]
(%o9)                       [      ]
                            [ 0  1 ]
(%i10) M2: for i thru 10
            do (genmatrix (lambda ([i, j], 1 - random(2)), 2, 2),
                if determinant(%%) # 0 then return(%%));
                            [ 1  0 ]
(%o10)                      [      ]
                            [ 1  1 ]
(%i11) M2: for i thru 10
            do (genmatrix (lambda ([i, j], 1 - random(2)), 2, 2),
                if determinant(%%) # 0 then return(%%));
                            [ 1  1 ]
(%o11)                      [      ]
                            [ 0  1 ]
```

Note that the first argument for `genmatrix` is a lambda expression (i.e. unnamed function). If you put the name of an array function such as `g` in your example, it will not have the intended effect, because in Maxima, array functions are memoizing functions, giving a stored output for an input that has been seen before. Obviously that's not intended if the output is supposed to be random.

Note also that `M2` will be assigned `done` if the for-loop runs to completion without finding a non-singular matrix. I think that's useful, since you can see if `M2 # 'done` to ensure that you did get a result.

Finally note that it makes a difference to use the "group of expressions without local variables" `(...)` as the body of the for-loop, instead of "group of expressions with local variables" `block(...)`, because the effect of `return` is different in those two cases.

Comment: Thank you very much! It seems as if this solution works for Maxima but not for STACK, but that is maybe part of another question.

Comment: I don't know much about STACK, you might have to find a STACK-specific forum to ask about that.